# Getting the error : 'The code execution cannot proceed because hdf5.dll was not found' in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0, hdf5

I am using Visual Studio 2015 & OpenCV 3.4.1 (along with the contrib_modules) in Windows 10. The project builds successfully but when I run the project I am getting the System error 'The code execution cannot proceed because hdf5.dll was not found.Reinstalling the program may fix this problem '.

How can I resolve this problem? This is a screenshot of the error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7St.png)

Comment: Use a post-build event to xcopy *all* of the opencv dependencies to the build output directory. including hdf5.dll

Comment: @HansPassant can you please elaborate on this?  I don't have any idea on how to do the above procedure you mentioned.

Comment: You ought to have enough keywords to let Google help you.  Consider "visual studio how to use postbuild event to copy files".  Prefix the name of the language you use to get more relevant hits.

Comment: I resolved the error. I had to install the Anaconda Python env to get the correct hdf5.dll file. Once its installed, add the python tools for VS 2015 and restart the apps. It was a workaround, and it resolved the error!